# Save list items to a new list if the item contains specific substring

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I want to check if strings in a list of strings contain a certain substring. If they do I want to save that list item to a new list:

```
list = ["Maurice is smart","Maurice is dumb","pie","carrots"]
```

I have tried using the following code:

```
new_list = [s for s in list if 'Maurice' in list]
```

but this just replicates the list if one of its items is `'Maurice'`.
So I was wondering if, maybe, there was a way to solve this by using the following syntax:

```
if "Maurice" in list:
    # Code that saves all list items containing the substring "Maurice" to a new list
```

Result should then be:

```
new_list = ["Maurice is smart", "Maurice is dumb"]
```

If been looking for a way to do this but I can not find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this:

```
list = ["Maurice is smart","Maurice is dumb","pie","carrots"]

new_list = [x for x in list if "Maurice" in x]

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['Maurice is smart', 'Maurice is dumb']
```

Comment: For anyone reading this answer: I recommend strongly not to use python built in names for your own variables. Using list as variable name here will prevent users of your code from using the keyword list. This can have all sorts of bad consequences.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension.

Also, make sure not to use the built in `list` as variable name.

```
my_list = ["Maurice is smart", "Maurice is dumb", "pie", "carrots"]
[e for e in my_list if 'Maurice' in e]
```

Comment: thanks for mentioning not using ``list`` as variable name

Answer (score 3):

You could use Python's builtin [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
data = ["Maurice is smart", "Maurice is dumb", "pie", "carrots"]
res = filter(lambda s: 'Maurice' in s, data)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
['Maurice is smart', 'Maurice is dumb']
```

The first argument is a predicate function (a simple lambda here) which must evaluate to True for the element of the iterable to be considered as a match.

`filter` is useful whenever an iterable must be filtered based on a predicate.

Also, a little extra, imagine now this data to be filtered:

```
data = ["Maurice is smart","Maurice is dumb","pie","carrots", "maurice in bikini"]
res = filter(lambda s: 'maurice' in s.lower(), list)
print(res)
```

Ouput:

```
['Maurice is smart', 'Maurice is dumb', 'maurice in bikini']
```

Comment: Exactly why should filter be always preferable to list comprehensions? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1247490/2243104